# Text size of dynamically created UI components in Android

Tags: android

I have a `TableLayout` in my activity. Here is a row in it.

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_won"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/date_won"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prize_won"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/amount_won"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/claimed_or_not"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/claimed_or_not"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_won_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hyphen"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prize_won_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hyphen"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/claimed_or_not_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hyphen"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>
```

The following code adds table rows at runtime depending on how many rows there are in the database table.

```
    luckyDrawHisotry = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    contentRow = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.row_content);     
    LayoutParams contentRowLayoutParams = contentRow.getLayoutParams();
    dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_won_content);
    LayoutParams dateLayoutParams = dateText.getLayoutParams();
    prizeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prize_won_content);
    LayoutParams prizeLayoutParams = prizeText.getLayoutParams();
    claimedOrNot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.claimed_or_not_content);
    LayoutParams claimedLayoutParams = claimedOrNot.getLayoutParams();

            if (prizeDao.loadAll().size() > 0) {
        Prize prize = prizeDao.loadAll().get(0); 
        dateText.setText(Utils.stringFromDate(prize.getWinningDate()));
        prizeText.setText(prize.getPrizeName());
        if(prize.getPrizeRecieved())
            claimedOrNot.setText("yes");
        else
            claimedOrNot.setText("no");
    } 

    if (prizeDao.loadAll().size() > 1){     
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int pixelSize = (int) (12 * dm.scaledDensity);
        for (int i = 1; i < prizeDao.loadAll().size(); i++) {
            Prize prize = prizeDao.loadAll().get(i); 
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this); 
            lastRowId = lastRowId + 10;
            row.setLayoutParams(contentRowLayoutParams);
            row.setId(lastRowId);
            TextView dText = new TextView(this);
            dText.setLayoutParams(dateLayoutParams);
            dText.setTextSize(pixelSize);
            dText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            TextView pText = new TextView(this);
            pText.setLayoutParams(prizeLayoutParams);
            pText.setTextSize(pixelSize);
            pText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            TextView cText = new TextView(this);
            cText.setLayoutParams(claimedLayoutParams);
            cText.setTextSize(pixelSize);
            cText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            dText.setText(Utils.stringFromDate(prize.getWinningDate()));
            pText.setText(prize.getPrizeName());
            if(prize.getPrizeRecieved())
                cText.setText("yes");
            else
                cText.setText("no");
            row.addView(dText);
            row.addView(pText);
            row.addView(cText);
            luckyDrawHisotry.addView(row);
        }
    }
```

I created the first row for the table in the xml file so that I can compare the rows that are dynamically created with that created as xml.

The result is as follows.

[image]

As you can see, the row added by code is bigger than the row created by xml. Have I done anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want `12dip`

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12, 
                                        getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

from the documentation of `TypedValue.applyDimension`

> Converts an unpacked complex data value holding a dimension to its
>   final floating point value. The two parameters unit and value are as
>   in TYPE_DIMENSION.

Edit: only now I realized that you are using `sp` in your layout. To get `12sp`, you should change only the first parameter to: `COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, 
                                        getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

you can also use setTextSize that takes two paramters:

```
setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 12);
```

where the first is the unit. You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29)

Comment: The result is still the same.

Comment: sorry only now I realized that you are using `sp` in your layout and not `dip`. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Yes. I'm using sp. Thanks for helping.

Comment: The error still occurred but when I set the text size to 6, it worked.

Comment: it's strange. Can you tried with my last edit `setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 12);` ?

Comment: I think your answer is right. It's probably an emulator problem. It worked fine with Google's emulator but doesn't work on GenyMotion's.